# VBA - assign slots by groups

Tags: vba, excel

I have a varying number of slots (as in "playing fields") and have to assign them to a varying number of groups (e.g. 4 Fields, for 2 groups, so each group gets assigned 2 fields to play on).

In the beginning I thought I could get around it in Excel by dividing the number of "playing fields" by the number of groups and then round down:

```
= ROUNDDOWN(B6/B5;0)
```

but now, if the numbers don't "fit", there are empty fields.

I can do this in Excel or in VBA (but VBA would be more practical I guess).

I tried googling for results, but I can't figure out "what to google for". I'm guessing the problem has been solved by others already under different names / uses.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to approach this? Especially under the circumstances that the number of groups, as well as the number of "playing fields" vary? I'd like to automate the assignment with VBA in Excel.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but here is a code, that will help you assign all the fields. Try this:

```
Sub AssignSlots()
    Dim groupCount As Long, fieldCount As Long, rest As Long, fieldsPerGroup As Long, i As Long

    groupCount = 6 'Range("B6").Value
    fieldCount = 10 'Range("B5").Value
    'if we don't have enought fields, exit program
    If fieldCount < groupCount Then
        MsgBox "There are less fields than groups!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'calculate how many fields per group (Int(...) performs rounding down)
    fieldsPerGroup = Int(fieldCount / groupCount)
    'calculate rest of fields
    rest = fieldCount - fieldsPerGroup * groupCount

    For i = 1 To rest
        'assign fieldsPerGroup + 1 fields to groups
    Next

    For i = rest + 1 To groupCount
        'assign fieldsPerGroup fields to rest of groups
    Next
End Sub
```

In the above program, groups 1-4 will have 2 fields assigned and groups 5 and 6 will have 1 field.